# Exclude incomplete classes from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame and from it I'm plotting some trend lines, however, I want to exclude data where there aren't complete records (i.e. if the dose of drug C is NA in 2002, then I don't want C included on the plot at all). How do I achieve this in R?

Reproducible Example

```
df <- data.frame(year=c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004),
                 dose=c(500, 600, 750, 550, 300, 330, 350, 390, 100, NA, 250, 125),
                 drug=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"))
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x = year, y = dose, color=drug))
```

Comment: `dfplot <- df[!df$drug %in% unique(df[is.na(df$dose), "drug"]),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tidyverse approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)
gplot(df %>% group_by(drug) %>% filter(!any(is.na(dose))))+
 geom_line(aes(x = year, y = dose, color=drug))
```

It filters now per drug (from `group_by`) if there is not `!` any na-value